# Magento 2 : Product pages through exceptions

Tags: magento2, product, exception

All Magento products were working properly last week. Now I check that all product pages through exceptions.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 1350


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 1350
```

Please have a look, it's urgent
Any help is really appreciated

Comment: there is something wrong in your catalog product XML file.  Can you tell me your magento version

Comment: my Magento version is 2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, please remove after attribute from referenceBlock. You can not use after and before attribute in referenceContainer tag.

If you want to use after or before. you can use this on move tag like below.

```
 <move element="element name" destination="where you want to move" after="">
```

Comment: Where I can find this file

Comment: please check your current theme. app/design/frontend/[Vendor][Yourtheme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: or if you have installed any third-party module which is related to the product details page. Then look into the XML file of 3rd party extension.

Comment: This is not working for me even after disable all the modules